# Should it (always) be "contact me" or (sometimes) "contact with me"?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I think it should always be "contact me" as contact is a transitive verb and should be followed by an object. But could someone clarifies? Is "contact with me" correct usage in some context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When used as a verb, "contact" is always transitive. As such, you are correct: it should always be "contact me."

Note that the phrase "contact with me" may appear as an object in other situations, where it may be mistaken for a verb. Example: *The other day, my long lost brother **made contact with me**.* In this example, *made* is the verb, and *contact* is its direct object.

Comment: As @rintaun points out, "contact" is always transitive *when used as a verb*.  There was a very long and bitter battle over whether it was ever correct to do so; nowadays, we "verb" words all the time, but in the early-to-mid 20th century it was a new and shocking thing to do.  Rex Stout's famous fictional detective Nero Wolfe (one of my favorite characters) would turn away a client, or significantly increase his already-outrageous fee, if the client used "contact" as a verb.

Answer (score 0):

As contact is also  intransitive verb, I see no objection to the phrase "I'll contact with you soon", especially if used in a business/professional context.

Comment: "**As** *contact* is" requires some sort of evidence. (*Contact* is only listed as transitive in the OED)

Answer (score 0):

"to contact" is mostly handled as a transitive verb. "to contact with me" seems to be occasional use as Ngrams shows:

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=contact%20me%2C%20contact%20with%20me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccontact%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontact%20with%20me%3B%2Cc0)

"to contact with sb" was in use long before "to contact sb". Maybe it was influenced by "get in contact with me". Later the simple transitive version got the better of it.

Comment: Your NGram is for "contact with me", not "to contact with me", the difference being that the former includes nouns. You wouldn't get [any results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+contact+me%2Cto+contact+with+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20contact%20me%3B%2Cc0) for "to contact with me" because it's not used in English.